# what are the opensource libraries used in SXA

Tags: sxa

I am using Sitecore 9.3 with SXA and i want to know the opensource libraries that are used by SXA, any advise?

Comment: Hi NAli, This question may be more suitable for the Sitecore Chat on Slack or as a support ticket with Sitecore. You are more than welcome to explore the media library and SXA to come to your own conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to explore package content.

Inside **Copyrights** folder (`files\sitecore\Copyrights\*`) you will find license information for libraries used in this module.

For **SXA 9.3**:

- AjaxMin_Apache.txt
- fullcalendar_MIT.txt
- galleria_MIT.txt
- hammer.js_MIT.txt
- jquery.hammer.js_MIT.txt
- jQueryFlash_MIT_GPL.txt
- lodash_MIT.txt
- mediaelement_MIT.txt
- NewtonSoft.Json_MIT.txt
- prismjs_MIT.txt
- SolrNet_Apache.txt
- Spatial4n.Core_Apache.txt
- typehead.js_MIT.txt

Comment: any idea why Scriban doesn't appear ?